# Can we use PostgREST with CockroachDB

Tags: postgresql, cockroachdb, postgrest

[PostgREST](https://github.com/PostgREST/postgrest) serves a fully RESTful API from any existing PostgreSQL database.

[CockroachDB](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/) promises distributed SQL advantages.

CockroachDB is built to be largely compatible with PostgreSQL. Here is a [detailed blog on this](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/blog/why-postgres/)

If we can bring these two together that's a powerful combination. We could automatically generate RESTful API for CockroachDB using PostgREST.

Is PostgREST compatible with CockroachDB ?

Has anyone used this combination on a production application ?

Comment: Right it doesn't work because CockorachDB doesn't support SET LOCAL. See https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/issues/32562#issuecomment-662105805

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Steve Chavez commented, PostgREST is not currently compatible with CockroachDB since CockroachDB doesn't support `SET LOCAL`. See https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/issues/32562#issuecomment-662105805 for more details.

Comment: The linked issue suggests that this is now resolved (within a year or so of the answer). I'd love to know if cockroachdb now works with postgREST.

Answer (score 1):

There is a project called [universal-database-proxy-rest](https://github.com/mcadecio/universal-database-proxy-rest). It is very similar to PostgREST but its more simplistic and relies on the database metadata. It is both compatible with CockroachDB and PostgresDB.

Here's an example of how to use with Docker.

Create a docker-compose.yml with the following contents:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  crdb:
    image: cockroachdb/cockroach:v22.1.0
    ports:
      - "26257:26257"
    command: start-single-node --insecure
    volumes:
      - ./init-cockroach.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    healthcheck:
      test: cockroach sql --insecure
      interval: 1s
      timeout: 3s
      retries: 5
  db-rest-api:
    environment:
      CRB_PASSWORD:
    image: mcadecio/universal-database-proxy-rest:0.0.6
    depends_on:
      crdb:
        condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      - "8010:8010"
    volumes:
      - ./config.json:/usr/database-proxy/config.json
```

This docker-compose just has 2 services. The CockroachDB and the Rest API that will be generated by the tables found in the DB.

Create a file named `init-cockroach.sql` with following contents:

```
CREATE SCHEMA vehicles;

CREATE TABLE vehicles.cars
(
    car_id       bigint primary key not null
        constraint cars_car_id_uindex unique,
    manufacturer varchar(50)        not null,
    doors        bigint default 5
);

INSERT INTO vehicles.cars
VALUES (1, 'BMW', 5),
       (2, 'BMW', 3),
       (3, 'MERCEDES', 5),
       (4, 'MERCEDES', 3);

CREATE TABLE vehicles.wheel
(
    wheel_type varchar(50) primary key not null
);
```

We will use this to pre-seed our database with some data.

Next create a file name `config.json` with the following:

```
{
  "cockroachApi": {
    "enabled": true,
    "host": "0.0.0.0",
    "port": 8010,
    "openApiFilePath": "crbOpenApi.yaml",
    "database": {
      "host": "crdb",
      "port": 26257,
      "username": "root",
      "password": "CRB_PASSWORD",
      "databaseName": "defaultdb"
    }
  }
}
```

Here we are just setting the port we want the REST API to be exposed and the database connection details.

Now its all setup. Just do:
`docker compose up` or `docker-compose up` (depending on your docker setup)

On your browser go to http://localhost:8010/docs you will see the Swagger UI and the endpoints available. You can try them out on the browser.
[Swagger Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/109wJ.png)

If you want to know more about this project head to: https://github.com/mcadecio/universal-database-proxy-rest

Feel free to provide any feedback.

Answer (score 1):

With the 22.2 release of CockroachDB and beyond, PostgreREST as of version 10.0.0 works with CockroachDB.

Docs pointing to support: https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/releases/v22.2#v22-2-0-database-operations